# Cannot extract xcode 8 beta 3

Tags: xcode8, xar, xcode8-beta3

I have downloaded it 3 times. Twice in safari and once in chrome.

Every time I cannot unarchive it with the default tool, or with Unarchiver.

Based on [this apple developer thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48923) I tried:

```
$ xar -xf Xcode_8_beta_3\ \(1\).xip 
Error while extracting archive:(Content): archived-checksum sha1's do not match (No such file or directory)
```

Then:

```
$ cpio -it < Xcode_8_beta_3\ \(1\).xip 
Content
cpio: Truncated input file (needed 4433260676 bytes, only 4433260317 available): Unknown error: -1
```

I have 25 gigs of free space on my drive with this file present (but if it was a disk space issue why is it saying my compressed archive is too small by ~250 bytes?)

I'm using OSX 10.11.4

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Seems to me like you have a corrupted/incomplete download.

Comment: This only works on 10.11.5 (or later)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar problems.  It would just hang verifying.   I was able to successfully extract after updating macOS to 10.11.6.

I also cleared out about 50 GB at the same time but I think I already had enough space to begin with.

Comment: Shoot, I didn't want to do that update. I heard there were some serious keychain issues and I don't want to roll back my whole OS. you've been fine though?

Comment: No issues that I have noticed.  Xcode 8 beta 3 has randomly crashed several times but not much different from previous betas.  

Comment: I updated to this version of OSX. I had to redownload the beta, but now it extracts successfully. Thanks Matt. Unbelievable solution for the way this problem presents.

Comment: Agreed it is a weird solution to a weird problem.

Comment: Crazy stuff.. same problem here. Should not need to update OS.

Answer (score 3):

i had similar issues.
I had OSX 10.11.4 when i faced the issue,so i updated to OSX 10.11.6.
Not able to extract .xip file.
Then i tried the below command and that did the trick for me.

```
 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode_8_beta.xip
```

Comment: Thanks! Heads up, for newer betas you'll need to append the version to the file name (like Xcode_8_beta_3.xip). Also make sure to run this command in the directory where you downloaded the file.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Jakuben . I forgot to mention.

Comment: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine this comes while I tried this

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 During

```
Error Picture
```

[image]

```
Step One Picture
```

[[image]]

```
Step Two Picture
```

[[image]]

```
Step Three Picture DONE
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade MAC OS to **OS X 10.11.6**

This is the minimum requirement to install xcode 8. Otherwise it shows error when we extract Xcode_8.xip

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `unzip`, Unarchiver, and other tools, but ultimately the only thing that opened it was [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/). However, Pacifist was really slow so I just ended up downloading Xcode from the App Store.