# Xcode 9 - Downloadable xip file is corrupt from apple site

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra, xcode9beta6

I have downloaded the new Xcode 9 build from the Apple website

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

However, I am getting the following error when extracting the file

[image]

Is this a known issue with the downloadable file or do I need to do something else in order to extract the `xip` file.

My Mac config

```
High Sierra
System Version: macOS 10.13 (17A352a)
Kernel Version: Darwin 17.0.0
```

Comment: I see you are using an app to un"xip" it.  Why not try the native OSX unzip?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like the software I was using to unzip https://theunarchiver.com/ didn't support `xip` format fully. Switching to the native `osx` unzip solved the issue

Comment: Thanks ! You saved me from couple of times trying to re-download the file !

Comment: Dude you just saved my day ... I'm on Catalina tried download every version of Xcode that supports Catalina and ended up 'data is corrupted' error. After making sure there is more than enough room of hard drive space then I saw your solution. You are the HERO !

Answer (score 0):

I was having older version of MacOS then required for given Xcode's xip file. Thats why it was giving me above error. Once I Updated my MacOS to required version. The same xip started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

During Swift 5 I want to install the old Xcode and i am DONE with just some step
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096470/6881070

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096470/6881070
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `unzip`, Unarchiver, and other tools, but ultimately the only tool which was even able to open the file was [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/). However, Pacifist was really slow so I just ended up downloading Xcode from the App Store.